# Default behavior for mock inherited from object instance

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I'm wondering if it's possible the following approach to create a mock which would have behavior inherited from an actual instance:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void DoTest()
    {
        A realA = new A();
        Mock<IA> aMock = CreateMockBasedOnRealA(); ///???

        Assert.That(aMock.Object.Do(1, 2), Is.EqualTo(3));
    }
}

public sealed class A : IA
{
    public int Do(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}

public interface IA
{
    int Do(int a, int b);
}
```

If the A class weren't sealed it would be possible to create a mock based on the class itself, however, I will not be able to mock Do method because it's not virtual, so I'd do something like this:

```
[Test]
public void DoTest()
{
    A realA = new A();
    Mock<IA> aMock = new Mock<IA>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    aMock.Setup(a => a.Do(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns((int a, int b) => realA.Do(a, b));
    Assert.That(aMock.Object.Do(1, 2), Is.EqualTo(3));
}
```

But then if my class has tens methods like Do and bunch of properties I will have to have a separate setup for each of them.

Is there any shortcut for the stuff above?

Comment: First of all, you obviously only have to mock the methods being called by the class you are testing. You cannot mock non-virtual and non-interface methods. This is due to the way mock frameworks use reflection but your need to do so is perfectly valid imo. What I always do is wrapping 3rd party classes in my own classic e.g I have an IThreadSleepHelper class, and IWebClientHelpet etc.

Comment: Why mock at all if you're using a real instance?

Comment: The idea to have a partial mock based on the actual implementation. It's useful when I can use a real object but at the same time with an ability to mock some of its methods on the fly.