# Returning default mock results from actual objects' instances

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing, moq, .net-6.0

Consider a scenario when you need to write `integration tests` for the `REST API` controllers. I use `MSTest` for this. The logic is following:

1. Create new `database`, run init `SQL` migrations
2. Create test `HTTP Client` and make calls against `endpoints`
3. Dispose of test `DB`.

**Use-case** Most of the endpoints do validation, whether `SQL` command (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) returned a success result (boolean `true`) or not. To replicate this scenario I either need to know exact `SQL` failure conditions (hard), or, the easier option is **to be able to mock repositories**. Sure this is no longer an complete integration test, but at least I am able to test `REST` business logic that way and `HTTP response status codes`. Additional benefit is testing DB transaction rollback functionality.

**Question** Therefore, I would like to know - it it possible to create a mock, that would return all values of actual object instance by default, unless `setup()` override is provided?

**Example/working code**  On test initialization, we create an instance of a HTTP test client and a mocked repository:

```
_usersRepo = new UsersRepository(); // actual instance of repository

var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>()
.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
{
    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
        _usersRepoMock = new Mock<IUsersRepository>();

        // setting mock just for 1 of the methods manually
        _usersRepoMock
            .Setup(p => p.GetByIdAsync(It.IsAny<long>()))
            .Returns(async (long r) => await _usersRepo.GetByIdAsync(r));

        services.AddSingleton<IUsersRepository>(_usersRepoMock.Object);
    });
});
_client = application.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions());
```

See that I have manually configured a mock to return the results **from an actual repository** for a single method.

Then, in a test class, whenever I need something to fail I do the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Db_throws_exception()
{
    _usersRepoMock.Setup(p => p.GetByIdAsync(It.IsAny<long>())).Throws(new System.Exception("test"));
    //.. rest of the code
}
```

This solution works as expected, HOWEVER, the problem is that in order for this approach to work I need to manually proxy all mock object requests to actual instances. I have around 4-6 methods in each repo and about 8 different repos (more in the future) **and I would like to avoid doing it**. Is it possible?

Here is what I want to avoid doing:

```
_usersRepoMock = new Mock<IUsersRepository>();
_usersRepoMock.Setup(p => p.GetByIdAsync(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(async (long r) => await _usersRepo.GetByIdAsync(r));
_usersRepoMock.Setup(p => p.Create(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(async (long r) => await _usersRepo.Create(r));
_usersRepoMock.Setup(p => p.Update(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(async (long r) => await _usersRepo.Update(r));
    
_repo2Mock = new Mock<IRepo2>();
_repo2Mock.Setup(p => p.Method1(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(async (long r) => await _repo2.Method1(r));
_repo2Mock.Setup(p => p.Method2(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(async (long r) => await _repo2.Method2(r));
_repo2Mock.Setup(p => p.Method3(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(async (long r) => await _repo2.Method3(r));
_repo2Mock.Setup(p => p.Method4(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(async (long r) => await _repo2.Method4(r));
_repo2Mock.Setup(p => p.Method5(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(async (long r) => await _repo2.Method5(r));

_repo3Mock = new Mock<IRepo3>();
_repo3Mock.Setup(p => p.Method1(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(async (long r) => await _repo3.Method1(r));
_repo3Mock.Setup(p => p.Method2(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(async (long r) => await _repo3.Method2(r));
_repo3Mock.Setup(p => p.Method3(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(async (long r) => await _repo3.Method3(r));
_repo3Mock.Setup(p => p.Method4(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(async (long r) => await _repo3.Method4(r));
_repo3Mock.Setup(p => p.Method5(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(async (long r) => await _repo3.Method5(r));
```

There are some similar questions on stackoverflow, but I couldn't find the same use-case as mine nor an acceptable answer to the problem.. Here is one example: [Default behavior for mock inherited from object instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231520/default-behavior-for-mock-inherited-from-object-instance)

p.s. I have probably spent more time writing this question than it was to write the code for mocks :)

Comment: In case of integration test you should not mock any of your classes/interfaces. If you call a downstream system then you can have a fake http server. If you perform some operation against a database then use an in-memory database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want using one of the overloads of the `Mock` constructor.

First, create an implementation of `IUsersRepository` in your test project and make sure all its members are virtual. Implement all members using the default behavior.

```cs
class TestUsersRepository : IUsersRepository
{
    public virtual async Task<User> GetByIdAsync(long id)
    {
        // (...)
    }

    // (...)
}
```

Then in your test, create a `Mock` using your test repository.

You should now be able to override the members that you want using the `Setup` method.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public async Task Db_throws_exception()
{
    var mockRepo = new Mock<TestUsersRepository>(() => new TestUsersRepository());
    mockRepo .Setup(p => p.GetByIdAsync(It.IsAny<long>())).Throws(new System.Exception("test"));
    //.. rest of the code
}
```